# Who to give notice to?

Tags: quitting, notice-period

Basically, I just was offered a new job and am planning to give my notice at the current one. The confusing part is that I just got word that I am going to be transferred to a new office and will have a new manager pretty much effective on the date I was planning to give as my last day.

I have never met the new manager. It doesnt really impact my current managers anymore because they're planning on me leaving due to the transfer and I've never met the new manager to be able to contact him and tell him I dont plan to stay.

My question is, who do I give my notice to?

Comment: While this may technically be company-specific regulations, pretty much all companies handle this the same way. And it's not really a legal question. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 12):

Give your notice to the person who is your manager on the day you give notice. She will make sure that everyone else who is impacted is informed.

Comment: I agree with this, although I'd also suggest contacting the other manager more informally to let them know, particularly if you've already made the move

Answer (score 4):

You give your notice to your current managers. Wether they are impacted by your resignation is irrelevant.And while you give notice to your current managers, you can ask them whether you need to inform the manager you are being transferred to.